# Bigquery stream: 'Failed to insert XX rows due to timeout'

Tags: google-bigquery

Recent days, our streaming met with

```
"Failed to insert XX rows. First error: {"errors":[{"reason":"timeout"}],"index":YY}"
```

During the past half month of continuous streaming from unchanged data source and program scripts, no such failure has been found before.

project id: red-road-574

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fellow BigQuery team member here.

It looks like our documentation is a bit incorrect, in that we can have partial commit of the rows. We'll fully reject the request if there are invalid rows (structure mismatch), but individual rows may fail to be buffered.

In this case, only the rows indicated failed to commit. If you have an insert id you can simply retry the failed rows, or retry the full request if desired (though each retried row will count against your table quota).

This increased occurrence of these row-level errors is due to a change around how we handle batches of insertions. Previously, the entire request would have encountered a timeout.

Hope that helps.
Sean

Comment: 1. Is the failed insert id contained in the error info? Otherwise, I've no idea which ones are failed nor not. As for my observation for now, I didn't see insert id in error info.   
2. It seems like from next year stream will be charged based the number of requests, we are concerned that this type of performance issue will increase our cost a lot.
3.  Our data structure will be permanent once being set, so I don't think( and I also double checked our data though) there are any structure mismatches. Are there any other type of "invalid"?

Comment: In the insertErrors list, each error has an "index" property. That corresponds to the index of the row in the original request.  
  
The charging will be based on # of deduplicated rows successfully accepted, so this should have no impact on your cost.  
  
Finally, we're working on updating the documentation right now to detail the set of expected "reason"s returned, as well as the suggested action. That should be updated within a day or so. That said, There are:  
stopped: row is fine, retry as is.  
invalid: row had a schema mismatch.

Comment: (I suck at stack overflow)

stopped: row is fine but not committed, retry as is. (usually happens because of a schema error with a different row)  
invalid: row had a schema mismatch. Don't retry.
timeout: row timed out, unknown commit state. Retry as is.
internalError: Some unknown error occurred with the row... retry might help (and might not).

Retries should all follow an exponential backoff pattern, and optionally queued somewhere for long-delay retry.

Answer (score 5):

We just rolled out a change over the weekend that should significantly lower the number of timeouts you encounter.

Over the last couple of weeks, the `TableData.insertAll` API has seen a massive increase in load from customers. While we should be able to handle that load without a problem, it has exposed a couple of bottlenecks in our system that we've been working to address. From our monitoring, it looks like the latency should be back to normal as of yesterday evening. If you continue to see timeouts, please let us know.

Comment: Does this timeout mean the whole request fail? (I hope so). And can I simply retry? will it duplicate data?(if I have insertId)

Comment: still happens (EST time): 
2014-08-18 13:50:34,743 FATAL Failed to insert 1 rows. First error: {"errors":[{"reason":"timeout"}],"index":473}
2014-08-18 13:54:34,200 FATAL Failed to insert 18 rows. First error: {"errors":[{"reason":"timeout"}],"index":5}
2014-08-18 13:55:45,128 FATAL c.g.b.b.u.BigqueryHelper  Failed to insert 2 rows. First error: {"errors":[{"reason":"timeout"}],"index":32}
2014-08-18 13:56:06,583 FATAL Failed to insert 4 rows. First error: {"errors":[{"reason":"timeout"}],"index":104}
2014-08-18 13:56:06,802 FATAL Failed..

Comment: If you use an insertid, it should be safe (and it is recommended) to retry.

Comment: Morning @Jordan Tigani, how's it going? I should say, lots of such failure right now.

Comment: I do see a latency spike at around 7 am Pacific time. I'll look into it. It seemed pretty short-lived, so if you retried, it should have succeeded pretty soon.

Comment: I see this issue frequently in logs. I had retries configured as well. But it ends up with same error. Can you confirm if timeout happens only on structure mismatch or if it's something on BigQueryAPI? I see this issue intermittently as I go through same set of data each time for streaming batch inserts. @Sean Chen