# On streaming inserts we got timeout but only for certain rows

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a streaming insert with 72 lines, but the error message is empty, and the `reason` is `timeout`, but only for the first 3 lines.

```
Error on line 0, reason: timeout, msg: 
Error on line 1, reason: timeout, msg: 
Error on line 2, reason: timeout, msg:
```

How is this possible, and shall we replay only these 3 lines or the rest of the rows too?

We have Case 05044644 on paid google enterprise support.

code segment is:

```
$resp = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllResponse();
$resp = $bq->tabledata->insertAll($project_id, $dataset_id, static::tableId(), $request);
$errors = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllResponseInsertErrors();
$errors = @$resp->getInsertErrors();
if (!empty($errors)) {
    $error_msg = '';
    if (is_array($errors)) {
        $line = 0;
        foreach ($errors as $eP) {
            $arr = $eP->getErrors();
            if (is_array($arr)) {
                foreach ($arr as $e) {
                    switch ($e->getReason()) {
                        case "stopped":
                            break;
                        default:
                            $error_msg.= sprintf("Error on line %s, reason: %s, msg: %s\r\n", $line, $e->getReason(), $e->getMessage());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->setErrorMessage($arr);
            }
            $line++;
        }
        $this->setErrorMessage($error_msg);
    } else {
        $this->setErrorMessage($errors);
    }
    //print_r($errors);
    //exit;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing the reply from [Bigquery stream: 'Failed to insert XX rows due to timeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364273/bigquery-stream-failed-to-insert-xx-rows-due-to-timeout):

BigQuery can have partial commit of the rows. We'll fully reject the request if there are invalid rows (structure mismatch), but individual rows may fail to be buffered.

In this case, only the rows indicated failed to commit. If you have an insert id you can simply retry the failed rows, or retry the full request if desired (though each retried row will count against your table quota).

The increased occurrence of these row-level errors since August is due to a change around how we handle batches of insertions. Previously, the entire request would have encountered a timeout.